# make route with iron router meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, router

I'm new to meteor and iron router. Iron router example are not up to date and not working on github.
I just want to make a simple route. 
Here is my /client/index.html

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    {{> template1OrTemplate2 depending on url}}
  </body>
</html>


<template name="template1">
  one
</template>

<template name="template2">
  two
</template>
```

my /lib/router.js:

```
Router.route('/templateOne', function () {
  // renderMyTemplate1 please
});

Router.route('/templateTwo', function () {
  // renderMyTemplate2 please
});
```

How is it possible something that easy is so hard to find?

Comment: Iron Router is good, but, FlowRouter is the way forward in terms of the Meteor eco system.

Comment: http://meteor-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/routing/

Comment: this is the docs for flow router https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router

Comment: also, to get started https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/introduction-to-flow-router

Comment: I already watch flowrouter but it still looks complexe for just routing. And I didn't find how to do my example with flowrouter

Comment: it is super easy with flow router....just as easy if not easier than iron router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Flow Router :-

ensure you have done...

```
meteor add kadira:flow-router kadira:blaze-layout
```

then

```
FlowRouter.route('/templateOne', {
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render("template1");
    }
}) 

FlowRouter.route('/templateTwo', {
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render("template2");
    }
})
```

With a layout you'd do something like

```
<template name="layout">
  <div>My App</div>
   {{>Template.dynamic template=content}}
  </template>
```

then

```
FlowRouter.route('/templateOne', {
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render("layout", {content:"template1"});
    }
})
```

Comment: with your example, template are display but I still got error:  Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/two." . And I dont understand your last example. Your are rendering the template layout on the url templateOne with the cotnent of template1 and it still working with template2.

Comment: not sure about your error,  the second example is where you use a layout....  you can render different templates into that layout.... so if you have a menu, depending on what you click on in the menu, you will redner different templates perhaps

Comment: You helped me a lot with flow router, I thought I understand well but I still got problem with layout. Could you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356401/meteor-with-flow-router-layout-is-rendered-twice

Answer (score 1):

Actually iron:router is [well documented](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/), and this is as trivial as you would expect.

```
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> yield}}
</body>


<template name="template1">
  one
</template>

<template name="template2">
  two
</template>



Router.route('/templateOne', function () {
  this.render('template1')
});

Router.route('/templateTwo', function () {
  this.render('template2')
});
```

However I agree with Keith's comments re flow-router.  If you are just starting you probably want to use that instead.

Comment: thanks it work but still got an error in the console: Uncaught Error: No Iron.Layout found so you can't use yield!. Can you show me the same example with flowrouter too? or a link to the doc?

Comment: when you add iron:router to a new project, iron:layout is included.
But you can add it individually, `meteor add iron:layout`

Comment: Here is a [meteorpad example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/YH9XPGh9KSKecbdZh/iron:router)